# Green's Theorem confusion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I have two equivalent forms of Green's theorem, namely
$$
\int\int_D \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}dxdy = \int_C pdx + qdy
$$
$$
\int\int_D \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial q}{\partial y}dxdy = \int_C pdy - qdx
$$
Moreover I know that the area of a simple closed curve is $A=\int_C xdy - ydx$.  I tried to verify this result using the **second version of** **Green's Theorem** by plugging $$F=(x,y)$$
However, though if I used this idea to evaluate the area of a circle by firstly parametrize it as $r=(a\cos\theta,a\sin\theta)$ Then calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} F.dr$ will just gives $0$. I know I can use the first version to get the correct, but why it fails if I try to use the second one?

Answer (score 1):

The area formula you are referring to is
$$A:={\rm area}(D)={1\over2}\int_{\partial D}(x\>dy-y\>dx)\ .$$
Here the RHS can be written as $\int_{\partial D}(p\>dy-q\>dx)$ with
$$p(x,y)={1\over2}x,\qquad q(x,y)={1\over2}y\ .$$
It follows that
$${\partial p\over\partial x}+{\partial q\over\partial y}={1\over2}+{1\over2}=1\ ,$$
so that your second formula gives
$${1\over2}\int_{\partial D}(x\>dy-y\>dx)=\int_D 1\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ ,$$
as desired.

(The function $F$ of three variables you have introduced has no place here.)

Comment: If I use your F=(x/2,y/2) then the area of a circle calculated after parametrisation will be 0 when integrating $F.dr$ unless I made a mistake in calculating that integral.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use the vector field $\vec F = \langle -y,x,0 \rangle$, not $\vec F = \langle x,y,0 \rangle$.

Comment: I understand that but just why F=(x,y,0) wouldn't work though? F=(x,y,0) works perfectly fine on the part where I had to verify the formula of the area.

Comment: You stated you wanted to use the **second** form of Green's theorem. If $$\int_C x dy - y dx = \int_C P dx + Q dy$$ you need $P = -y$ and $Q = x$.

Comment: That is the **first version** I put up right? Sorry if I am being stupid and stubborn. I can verify using the first version but using the second version I have no idea why my integral appears to be 0 when calculating the area of a circle.